# xlsx4j to evaluate excel formulas

Tags: excel, docx4j, named-ranges

provided that xlsx4j satisfies the SpreadsheetML specs, can the following scenario/requirement be implemented using the library?

1. xlsx4j can read named ranges
2. xlsx4j can evaluate a formula that
   is defined in the spreadsheetML specs
3. xlsx4j can performs the following loop: update a named range
   VAR_A(let's say a variable in Excel),evaluate the formula-cells
   FORM_CELL_A in that uses the named range VAR_A, read the named range
   associated to FORM_CELL_A.

regards
I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xlsx4j doesn't include code for evaluating formulas.  Try Apache POI for that.  If JAXB support is important to you (thus making xlsx4j attractive to you), you could port the relevant POI code.  (Both projects are ASLv2 licensed)